# select a radio button using swicth and case

Tags: java, android

I'm using radio buttons with switch and case. When I click on the radio button I can pass the information, but when I click on another radio button the first radio button does not reset on the server.

Here is my code:

```
public void checkRadioButton() {
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.radioButtonYes:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 16, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonNo:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 17, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonGreet:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 18, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonCatch:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 19, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonDrop:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 20, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonHome:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 21, true);
                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonConcert:
                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 22, true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the id of your Radio group:

```
final int id = ((RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

then pass this id inside switch:

```
switch (id) {

                case R.id.radioButtonYes:

                    ModbusReq.getInstance().writeCoil(new OnRequestBack<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onSuccess " + s);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(String msg) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "writeCoil onFailed " + msg);
                        }
                    }, 1, 16, true);


                    break;

                case R.id.radioButtonNo
```

...

Comment: I can as soon as I click on another radio button I can reset the other radio button I pressed before?

Comment: I am trying to help, but couldn't get this question sorry. If my answer worked, mark it. If it didn't work then I don't know the answer. If you have other questions, ask in another thread.